# Writing unit test for Razor cshtml views to make sure they compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor

I'm working on a project which recently passed tests but crashed at runtime because lots of .cshtml Razor views couldn't successfully compile and so I want to write tests for the .cshtml files to ensure that they compile successfully and avoid any model runtime errors.

I've been searching online and cannot see a clear way of doing this.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction please? It just needs to be a simple test to check that the .cshtml views actually compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a separate controller that has a method for each of your views. Write tests for all of these methods and check for a HTTP 200 status code.